# CRM 2011, Page Error on Create new solution window

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have installed a fresh copy of CRM 2011 on Server 2008. I am trying to create a new solution but getting the following error. I have heard that IE 10 is not fully compatible with CRM 2011 so I have tried switching between compatibility view and older versions of IE but without any luck. Can anyone suggest me a way to fix this problem.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: which error do you see from the Developer Tools - console tab?

Comment: @GuidoPreite I have updated the question. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: did you try also IE9 or just the compatibility mode?

Comment: I have tried all options in available in developers tool.

Comment: Choose one: use IE <= 9 or UR >= 12. IE10 doesn't work with older UR versions. Also UR >= 12 allows you to use other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRM 2011 Rollup version was not compatible with IE 10. As it was a fresh installation so Rollup 6 was deployed. After updating to to Roll-up 8 and then 15ths solved the problem.